# Retaining focus on ListView when using KeyUp to capture function key

Tags: c#, wpf, listview, focus

I have a ListView that shows a list of search results. To make things easier, I want to tie F8 to the search button, so that the user can hit F8 on their keyboard and perform the search.

I'm doing something like this:

```
private void UserControl_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Key == Key.F8)
    {
        btnSearch.RaiseEvent(new RoutedEventArgs(Button.ClickEvent));
        lvResults.SelectedIndex = 0;
        lvResults.Focus();
    }
}
```

btnSearch actually sets the index and focus itself. And if the user clicks the button (or tabs to it and hits space), focus is set. If I remove the selectedindex and focus here, I get the same behavior (so this code is actually doing it again, and not needed).

With this code, if I hit F8, the first row is selected, but focus remains on the textbox I was in when I hit F8. This is undesirable, because the user would like to be able to hit up/down arrow to select the result they want.

**Note:** If I set focus to another control (not a list view) it works fine. Also, if I try casting the selected item into a ListViewItem, I get an error since it is a DataRowView in this case. I also tried removing the code in btnSearch and calling it directly, and this has the same result as well.

So, it is selecting the row correctly, but the listview is not taking focus, while it does if I click the button. And if I set another control to have focus, that works, just not this listview.

Comment: Have you tried adding: `e.Handled = true` to make sure that something else isn't taking the keystroke and trying to handle it.  Off the top of my head, I'm thinking the textbox is re-stealing the focus because it's handling the F8 key press after your user control handler fires.

Comment: Try using `FocusManager.SetFocusedElement` http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.focusmanager.setfocusedelement.aspx.  You need to call `FocusManager.GetFocusScope` first, and then use the returned `FocusScope` in the call to `SetFocusedElement`.

Comment: This also doesn't work. The closest I get was that if I do FocusManager.SetFocusedElement(this, lvResults) , all I have to do is hit tab to use the arrow keys. I would like to now remove the need to hit tab.

Comment: I just wrote a quick sample application, and your code actually works just fine.  So there must be something else going on here.  I can provide you my sample application if you would like.  Have you tried it from a "clean machine"?

Comment: I would love to see a sample. It may be due to something like in the theme, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a zip of a test project in which your code works just fine; this is just a junk test project that I do testing in when I'm trying to help out with SO questions, so ignore the other stuff in the project.  http://sdrv.ms/LuNKQt

Also, I would suggest reading: http://julmar.com/blog/mark/?p=52, it has a lot of good info on WPF focus.

Lastly, you can use Snoop (http://snoopwpf.codeplex.com/releases/view/73187) to try and monitor the program and try to see exactly what is going on.